# why sort_values() is diifferent form sort_values().values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort a dataframe by all columns,and I find a way to solve that using

```
df = df.apply( lambda x: x.sort_values())
```

and I used it to my data

```
text1 = text
text = text.apply( lambda x : x.sort_values())
text1 = text1.apply( lambda x : x.sort_values().values)
text.head()
text1.head()
```

why not `text = text.apply( lambda x : x.sort_values())` get a wrong answer,and what is the `.vaules)`function?

```
text.head()
    Wave    2881.394531 2880.574219 2879.75293  2878.931641 2878.111328
    N-1     0.220934    0.203666    0.205743    0.196011    0.176293
    N-10    0.432692    0.387074    0.395692    0.355331    0.358963
    N-11    0.483360    0.463233    0.456304    0.428930    0.421482
    N-12    0.365057    0.364417    0.385134    0.352451    0.350513
    N-13    0.492172    0.466263    0.480657    0.439115    0.404883


text1.head()
    Wave    2881.394531 2880.574219 2879.75293  2878.931641 2878.111328
    P+1    -21.297623   -25.141329  -21.097095  -31.380476  -38.847958
    P+2    -12.681051   -14.661134  -13.688742  -16.829298  -20.320133
    P+3    -8.164744    -13.097990  -11.784309  -15.419610  -17.822252
    P+4    -0.023353    -0.926852   -8.036203   -14.583183  -17.071484
    P+5     0.022854    -0.037756   -0.002519   -1.891178   -7.795961
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Pandas operations [align data based on their index](https://pandas.pydata.org/#library-highlights).
So consider for example

```
In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame([(10,1),(9,2),(8,3),(7,4)], index=list('ABDC'))

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
    0  1
A  10  1
B   9  2
D   8  3
C   7  4
```

When Pandas evaluates `df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())`,
it generates the Series:

```
In [24]: df[0].sort_values()
Out[24]: 
C     7
D     8
B     9
A    10
Name: 0, dtype: int64

In [25]: df[1].sort_values()
Out[25]: 
A    1
B    2
D    3
C    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

and then tries to combine these two Series into a resultant DataFrame. It does that by aligning the indices:

```
In [21]: df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())   
Out[21]: 
    0  1
A  10  1
B   9  2
C   7  4
D   8  3
```

---

In contrast, when the lambda function returns a NumPy array there is no index to align upon. So Pandas merely pastes the values from the NumPy array into a resultant DataFrame in the same order.

So, when Pandas evaluates `df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().values)`,
it generates the NumPy arrays:

```
In [26]: df[0].sort_values().values
Out[26]: array([ 7,  8,  9, 10])

In [27]: df[1].sort_values().values
Out[27]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and then tries to combine these two NumPy arrays into a resultant DataFrame with the values in the same order

```
In [28]: df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().values)   
Out[28]: 
    0  1
A   7  1
B   8  2
D   9  3
C  10  4
```

Comment: @ unutbu . great explanation.

Comment: That is a correct and detailed answer, thank you very much ！

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Based on pandas documentation, `sort_values()` return the DataFrame object itself, while `values()` return the numpy array representation of the values in the DataFrame. Since `apply()` applies the specified function across the axis of the DataFrame, the applied function must return the numpy array representation of that current row/column, instead of returning the whole DataFrame. That is why it gives you the wrong result when you are only using `sort_values()`.

You can read the more complete explanation at [sort_values() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [values() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), and [apply() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)