# Why does series[0] and series[0:1] yield different results?

Tags: python, pandas

So, `df['date']` returns:

```
0        2018-03-01
1        2018-03-01
2        2018-03-01
3        2018-03-01
4        2018-03-01
            ...    
469796   2018-06-20
469797   2018-06-20
469798   2018-06-27
469799   2018-06-27
469800   2018-12-06
Name: date, Length: 469801, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And, `df['date'].sort_values()` returns:

```
137241   2018-01-01
378320   2018-01-01
247339   2018-01-01
34333    2018-01-01
387971   2018-01-01
            ...    
109278   2018-12-06
384324   2018-12-06
384325   2018-12-06
109282   2018-12-06
469800   2018-12-06
Name: date, Length: 469801, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now `df['date'].sort_values()[0]` "ignores sorting" and returns:

```
Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00')
```

Whereas `df['date'].sort_values()[0:1]` actually returns:

```
137241   2018-01-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Why the **apparently** inconsistent behaviour? As @cs95 accurately pointed out they return a scalar and a Series respectively, which is okay. I am confused about the value, the first one is `2018-03-01` while the second one is `2018-01-01`.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Warning

Somehow similar to: [why sort_values() is diifferent form sort_values().values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292709/why-sort-values-is-diifferent-form-sort-values-values)

Comment: Before I set up an example, `df['date'].sort_values().iloc[0:1, :]`. Does that do as expected?

Comment: Er... nope, error: `Too many indexers`

Comment: `df['date'].sort_values()[0]` returns a scalar, `df['date'].sort_values()[0:1]` returns a Series. You have to understand how python's list slicing notation works first.

Comment: @cs95 thanks for taking the time to reply, but I still don't see how your comment helps. Perhaps you could elaborate a bit?

Comment: @cs95 I think you are missing my question point. The returned scalar and Series are different in type (obviously) but in content/value as well.

Comment: [0] represents a scalar, [0:1] represents a list with a single element. In the pandas world, you are returned a Series. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: [0, 1][0] returns a scalar, 0, and [0, 1][0:1] returns a list, [0]. Still both are/have 0.

Comment: This is one of the weird things about pandas. `df['date'].sort_values()[0]` actually sorts the series but then you don't ask for the item at the first position (0) but instead you ask for the one "labeled" 0 -- the first item in the original series. You can replace it with `df['date'].sort_values().iloc[0]`.

Comment: @ayhan, So `df['date'].sort_values()[0]` is really getting the row with index 0. I see now, thanks for clarifying mate.

Comment: Sorry, I was initially confused by what you were asking. Reopened the question and hopefully my answer supplements ayhan's helpful comments sufficiently. Let me know if we can help with any further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight difference in how indexing is interpreted for Pandas for scalar indexing vs slicing. Consider a simpler example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}).sample(frac=1)
df
   col1
4     1
1     4
0     5
3     2
2     3
```

Also note the result of `sort_values`:

```
df['col1'].sort_values()
4    1
3    2
2    3
1    4
0    5
```

When you call `df['col1'].sort_values()[0]` you actually get the value indexed by key `0`. Here it is implicitly calling `loc`:

```
df['col1'].sort_values()[0]     # just gets the value indexed by that key
# 5

df['col1'].sort_values().loc[0]
# 5
```

And when you slice with indexes, it is assumed they are integral rather than labels, meaning it is implicitly calling `iloc`:

```
df['col1'].sort_values()[0:1]   # just gets the first row  
4    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64


df['col1'].sort_values().iloc[0:1]
4    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

If you want the scalar index operation to return the same thing as the slice, use `iloc` or `iat` (singular value):

```
df['col1'].sort_values().iloc[0]
# 1

df['col1'].sort_values().iat[0]
# 1
```